# Importing XML using VBA. Each tag line on seperate cell

Tags: xml, vba, excel, import

I'm currently trying to write some VBA that will import an XML file into my spreadsheet. I currently have the below which does this however, all the XML goes into one cell. Is there anyway I could make each tag go into a separate cell? (See attached photo)

[Ideal Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsyPE.png)

```
Dim filter As String 
Dim caption As String
Dim Filename As String 
Dim Overall As Workbook 
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    filter = "Text files (*.xml),*.xlsm " caption = "Please Select an input file " Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

    Set Overall = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename)

         Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True

         wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
         wb.Close False
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
         Overall.Close
```

Comment: Does this code render the screenshot output? [Workbooks.OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838643.aspx) maps XML values to cells. No tag/attrib markup shows, only data.

Comment: It doesn't. The screenshot is how I would like it to look. Currently it outputs all the text into one cell. I also tried the code from the website you provided and that does similar. Thank you though !

Answer (score 0):

If your XML files are formatted with appropriate new lines after each XML tag, then this should do:

```
  Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

  Dim xmlFile As Scripting.File
  Set xmlFile = fso.GetFile(Filename)

  Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
  Set ts = xmlFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

  Dim i As Long: i = 2
  Dim ws as Worksheet
  Set ws = Workbooks("OutputWorkbook").Worksheets("OutputSheet")

  While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ts.ReadLine
        i = i + 1
  Wend

  ts.Close
  Set ts = Nothing
```

Needs a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, and you may need to tweak the overall code to place the text where you need to...